# Не работает урон от пули

Tags: unity3d

Народ помогите,я делаю урон от пули но при соприкосновение с обьектом с тэгом Vraginа ничего не происходит,как буддто этого обьекта и нет.Что делать??Помогите

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ammo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float destroyTime;
    public int valueDown;
    bool isAmmo = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Invoke("DestroyAmmo", destroyTime); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        
           
        
    }
    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.tag == "Vragina")
        {

            Debug.Log("Da ura");
            collider.GetComponent<Creatureshealth>().health -= valueDown;
            isAmmo = true;
            if (isAmmo == true)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }


        }
    }
    //void DestroyAmmo()
    //{
    //    Destroy(gameObject);

    //}
}
```

Comment: Vraginа != Vragina

Answer (score 2):

1. `Ammo` это амуниция, а пуля это `Bullet`
2. Почему `OnTriggerStay`, а не `OnTriggerEnter`?
3. События физики `Stay/Enter/Exit` не произойдёт с двумя неподвижными объектами. Изменение `Transform` это не движение а по сути телепортация, движение это `Rigidbody`.
4. В 99.9% случаях в играх стрельба это `HitScan`, а трейсинг пуль просто визуал. Вычисление столкновений малого объекта на высоких скоростях слишком затратны.